# What did Batman whisper?

Tags: dc, batman, dc-animated-universe

In the **Justice League** cartoon episode **The Enemy Below**, Deadshot tries to kill Aquaman, and the League stops him. Batman whispers something in Deadshot's ear to make him tell who is paying him. Superman overhears, but refused to tell Wonder Woman.

I can't take it any longer, what did Batman whisper?

Comment: Pretty sure it was "mapone"

Answer (score 33, accepted):

According to [Wikiquote](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Justice_League):

> In an interview, [Kevin Conroy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Conroy) said that the words he whispered during the recording session were "I know where you live, Floyd."

Comment: Awesome.  I never would have expected them to have written the line.

Comment: @Keen  It sounds like they didn't so much write it, as Conroy just said something awesome so they could record the mumble.  Because he IS Batman.